# How to configure Arango DB to use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Tags: cors, arangodb

How to configure ArangoDB to use CORS in MacOS.
The documentation is not clear for me.
They told to use:

> arangod --http.trusted-origin "http://localhost:8529"

Ok. But how to run this if service is starting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Startup parameters can easily be translated to the configuration file syntax, which is used for the arangod service.

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/administration-configuration.html#configuration-file-format

```
[http]
trusted-origin = http://localhost:8529
```

The configuration file should be located here:

`/usr/local/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`

In Text Editor, one can open the file with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the open dialog to bring up the go to path popup, then paste the path and confirm twice.